# Can I put smaller brake discs on my car than were on it?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-calipers

Could I put 256mm discs on where previously they had 270mm discs. Both sets apparently fit my car according to data info sites?

Comment: Only if the calipers and pads fit properly, otherwise you need to change them as well.

Answer (score 1):

They're highly unlikely to be interchangeable, even if they are the same in the other dimensions 1.4 cm is a lot of diameter to lose and you'll end up with a corresponding amount of the brake pad not contacting anything - and that's even assuming that it doesn't cause other problems.